# Bulk insert/update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

let's say i want to execute following mysql and few records already exists in table and there may be more than one record which already exists.
if this record `(21,'Helen','a')` and `(21,'Hui Ling','b')` already exists in table and i want to execute insert and update with where condition like.. `where name = "Helen" and grade="a"` then what should be my update query part.

```
INSERT INTO students (points,name,grade)
    VALUES
    (21,'Helen','b'),
    (21,'Helen','c' ),
    (21,'Samia','a'),
    (21,'Hui Ling','b'),
    (21,'Yumie','a'),
    (21,'Helen','a')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    grade = VALUES('a'),
```

Comment: What keys do you have on students?

Comment: I'm not clear on your logic - if you have helen,a and then try to insert helen,b then it should do so but it you then try to insert helen,c it should not? What would you expect your final values for helen to be after all the inserts?

Comment: Names are almost never unique in my experience but if that's what you want then name should either be the primary key or a unique key on students.

Comment: actually there is no primary key in records what i'm inserting/updating, id is primary key that is auto increment but when i'm inserting records the id doesn't matter.

Comment: Having a unique key on name matters because the on duplicate key clause has to find a duplicate key to do it's thing can you publish your students table schema please (show create table students)

Comment: you can take example of wordpress postmeta table, there is many post_id and that can have same meta_key and meta_values,
so it's like i'm inserting/updating post_meta value based on post_id and meta_key.

Comment: You should post self contained questions here, referring on to wordpress isn't helpful.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: this is database structure and database table
(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eWc_kjkZGfDKgDVm0HJP99xAeOb6EFsT)
(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LmbYxTdd8TeBJIp_435IMu0oNihLl2QP)
and i want to update meta_value in bulk where post_id=99 and meta_key='_sku' AND post_id=106 and meta_key='_price'
i have the same requirement but in wordpress there is no bulk query function i found.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to set the `grade` to what is passed in.  You want to use the `VALUES()` construct:

```
INSERT INTO students (points, name, grade)
    VALUES
        (21,'Helen','b'),
        (21,'Helen','c' ),
        (21,'Samia','a'),
        (21,'Hui Ling','b'),
        (21,'Yumie','a'),
        (21,'Helen','a')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE grade = VALUES(grade);
```

This will arbitrarily choose one of the values for the table.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9257ff/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: what if there is 2 record with same name but points is different and i want to keep both record in table and only i want to update where name='Helen' and grade='c' and name='Yumie' and grade = 'a'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you want here but you almost certainly need to look at your keys for example

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists students;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table students
    ->  (id int auto_increment primary key,points int,name varchar(20),grade varchar(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO students (points,name,grade)
    ->     VALUES
    ->     (21,'Helen','b'),
    ->     (21,'Helen','c' ),
    ->     (21,'Samia','a'),
    ->     (21,'Hui Ling','b'),
    ->     (21,'Yumie','a'),
    ->     (21,'Helen','a'),
    ->     (22,'Helen','z')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    ->     grade = VALUES(grade);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from students;
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| id | points | name     | grade |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 |     21 | Helen    | b     |
|  2 |     21 | Helen    | c     |
|  3 |     21 | Samia    | a     |
|  4 |     21 | Hui Ling | b     |
|  5 |     21 | Yumie    | a     |
|  6 |     21 | Helen    | a     |
|  7 |     22 | Helen    | z     |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table students;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> alter table students
    -> add unique key studentsk1(name,points);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO students (points,name,grade)
    ->     VALUES
    ->     (21,'Helen','b'),
    ->     (21,'Helen','c' ),
    ->     (21,'Samia','a'),
    ->     (21,'Hui Ling','b'),
    ->     (21,'Yumie','a'),
    ->     (21,'Helen','a'),
    ->     (22,'Helen','z')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    ->     grade = VALUES(grade);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 2  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from students;
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| id | points | name     | grade |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 |     21 | Helen    | a     |
|  2 |     21 | Samia    | a     |
|  3 |     21 | Hui Ling | b     |
|  4 |     21 | Yumie    | a     |
|  5 |     22 | Helen    | z     |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that in the first insert that helen is duplicated because there is no unique key for the ON DUPLICATE KEY to test. After the alter table to add a unique key the following insert detects duplicate keys an works as expected.